# VS 2015 upd 2 VSTest Agent Deployment takes forever

Tags: visual-studio-2015, deployment, automated-tests, windows-10, coded-ui-tests

Recently we upgraded the our environments to WS2016 and Win10Clients. 
To run automated UI tests we deploy the Test agent. 
We have the following situation:

The test agent is being deployed using it's own credentials, as interactive process. As we require keyboard and mouse inputs for the tests.

When it runs like this, the agent deployment works fine. 
However, if we run the test, it fails, as the agent is installed with different credentials. When we looked around the web, we found that the issue should be resolved by installing the agent using the same credentials as the credentials being used for the tests. When we run the step, this is the log (part of):

```
2017-04-05T13:37:43.6954289Z DistributedTests: Task 'CheckTestAgentInstallation' on machine '*:5985' is being run

2017-04-05T13:38:42.0459205Z DistributedTests: Task 'CheckTestAgentInstallation' on machine '*:5985' completed.

2017-04-05T13:39:42.0496827Z DistributedTests: Update test agent is disabled. Skipping test agent updates.

2017-04-05T13:39:42.0653094Z DistributedTests: Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' on machine '*:5985' is being run

2017-04-05T13:40:42.0646321Z DistributedTests: Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' on machine '*:5985' is taking time. Please Wait

2017-04-05T13:41:42.0705524Z DistributedTests: Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' on machine *:5985' is taking time. Please Wait
```

We let it run, and the last couple of lines stretched over 16 hours. It did continue if we manually log in while the script is running. As this has to run in automated fashion at night, we cannot rely on that.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Side question: Is it really required to install it using the same credentials as the credentials that run the tests? As we have 8-10 different types of users, it would mean reinstalling the agent 8-10 times, adding around an hour of total run time....

Just in case updating main post:

Additional logs from DTAExecutionHost.exe:
[Link](https://pastebin.com/0ibKvt1G)

Comment: An agent should not need to be deployed. It should be installed and then it is a resource that can be used as needed. Then use group policies to manage which users can make the agent run tests. The details are different for Domains (with active directory) versus Workgroups.

Comment: Additional logging:
[link](https://pastebin.com/0ibKvt1G)

Comment: We managed to proceed a little. 

First issue we came across is the autologon is not stable, sometimes it just won't log on. Claiming there is no log on service available to process the request. But when we manually enter the password again, it logs us in without problems.

Besides that, if it passes and proceeds to the Run Functional Test step, performance is horrible. DTA Executionhost keeps waiting for 3 minutes before starting the tests. Sometimes never starts the tests at all.